# Connection timed out: no further information. Verify the connection properties

Tags: java, sql-server, google-app-engine

Ocurré algo muy raro, estoy haciendo una aplicación web en java con app engine y sql server usando servicios rest, todo funciona aparentemente bien, pero solo una vez, es decir, tengo un endpoint que se conecta a una base de datos y ejecuta un Store Procedure, cuándo me conecto al endpoint por primera vez funciona correctamente, pero cuando lo hago por segunda vez me arroja el siguiente error:

> Connection timed out: no further information. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.

Es muy raro, pues tengo otras aplicaciones que se conectan a la misma base de datos, que igualmente usan app engine, que usan el mismo driver de sql y no tienen problema. no he logrado ver qué tiene esta de diferente.

Función del error:

```
@Override
public void register() throws DatabaseException {
    try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://xx.xxx.xxx.xx;databaseName=mydatabase", Config.USER, Config.PASSWORD);
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement
            = connection.prepareStatement("execute store_procedure")) {

        preparedStatement.executeQuery();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Logger.getGlobal().log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage());
        throw new DatabaseException();
    }
}
```

Pom:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.0.jre8</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a cerrar la conexión al final del método para asegurar que la reabres en la siguiente invocación.

```
connection.close();
```